# CMIS: Choice List of Dates contains values which are not suitable to update a Document

Tags: java, alfresco, cmis, apache-chemistry

this question is a carbon copy of the one in [Alfresco Community](https://community.alfresco.com/message/814676).

In our company we use Alfresco where we added new TestModel and ListDate property.
[image: alfresco model]

Next we use CMIS Apache Chemistry connector that returns list of choices:
[image: idea runtime]

When one of these values is chosen for update, error appears. For instance, if we choose the first one (2001-01-05 == 5 of January 2001)

```
HTTP Status 409 - constraint
Constraint violation: 0418520046 Found 1 integrity violations:
Invalid property value: 
Node: workspace://SpacesStore/eaf740b4-d22a-415a-9ca7-f58a8e115dbb
Name: vzv_diff
Type: {TestModel}DiffProperties
Property: {TestModel}ListDate
Constraint: 0418520045 The value is not an allowed value: 1/5/01 12:00 AM
```

First value in details:

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[
time=978681600000,
areFieldsSet=true,
areAllFieldsSet=true,
lenient=true,
zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT-08:00",offset=-28800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],
firstDayOfWeek=1,
minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,
ERA=1,
YEAR=2001,
MONTH=0,
WEEK_OF_YEAR=1,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,
DAY_OF_MONTH=5,DAY_OF_YEAR=5,DAY_OF_WEEK=6,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,
AM_PM=0,
HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,
MINUTE=0,
SECOND=0,
MILLISECOND=0,
ZONE_OFFSET=-28800000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

It worth noting that on "Client machine" time adjusted with  utc +3,
 whereas on "Server (where Alfresco is actually installed)" - utc -8.

Our assumption is that Alfresco expected 0:00 am or 0:00 pm and that 12 am is summarized from UTCs scales.
Despite the fact that this situation is already weird, adjusting time of that value in any way before update didn't help at all.
Let's say, setting hours

```
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
```

results in

```
HTTP Status 409 - constraint
Constraint violation: 0418520818 Found 1 integrity violations:
Invalid property value: 
   Node: workspace://SpacesStore/eaf740b4-d22a-415a-9ca7-f58a8e115dbb
   Name: vzv_diff
   Type: {TestModel}DiffProperties
   Property: {TestModel}ListDate
   Constraint: 0418520817 The value is not an allowed value: 1/5/01 12:00 PM
```

Apache Workbench behaves the same way (but it has no choices though):[image: workbench]
None of variants are suited here.

We have been struggling with this issue for number of days without success.

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property is having constraint a List of values.You have a wrong understanding of constraints.If you are adding a list constraint , you won't be able to add values which are not listed.

So you won't be able to add date values except the values which you have listed.**You need to remove constraints and only need to select the datatype as date.**

Adding constraint in d:date type will defiantly give error.Below is the reason for same.

**Updated:**

First thing , it will check while saving values is list of values, If you pass 2001-01-05 as value than it will allow in case of constraint,but as it is a string value it will not allow to save in d:date.Second thing, if you pass date object of java , than equality comparison on the applied constraint will fail.So you have 2 option in this case.

1. Change d:date to d:text
2. Remove constraints.

Comment: Sorry but I can't get you. Actually I described that I tried to use one of the value, presented in Choice List (returned from CMIS server side), and it failed with error. Then i tried to adjust it somehow to achieve the goal, without success either.

Comment: This is because the date format will be different.List of value constraint we should not apply to date.It is storing the value as string, so it will compare as string.if equality comparison fails it will not allow you to save values.

Comment: Krutik, does that mean that if i put String "2001-01-05" and push it to the update request, it will apply such value? I ll check that right now

Comment: well now it says java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'TM:ListDate' is a datetime property. Expected type '' but received a 'java.lang.String' property.
 at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.repository.ObjectFactoryI

Comment: It will throw exception  like this because , you are trying to save string values in date field.You need to remove constraints from this.

Comment: Huh? If I'd had such option I wouldn't have written this question. In our app User should have ability to choose desired value from combobox. And model designed in Alfresco should work as expected: if it provides choiceList values then each of these values should be suitable for update.

Comment: In that case change the type of d:date to d:text. Constraints are not designed for d:date type.If you put constraint it will definitely give error.

Comment: Hm, interesting thoughts.. I will offer such workaround for our Analytics. For me sounds ok - user won't see any difference between Date and "String which represents date". As long as it takes some time, i won't mark your answer as correct for a while. Let's see, maybe someone else suggest some another approach during this time. Anyway thank you, Krutik.